The camera on my Lenovo laptop is not working on Ubuntu 22.04.5 LTS
I have a Lenovo laptop. My camera is working 'sometimes' for short periods of time, then suddenly stops working.
Here is the output of my lsusb, as you can see the camera is not present:
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 25a7:2410 Areson Technology Corp Laser mouse
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 8087:0026 Intel Corp. AX201 Bluetooth
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub

The output of v4l2-ctl:
v4l2-ctl --list-devices
Cannot open device /dev/video0, exiting.

My kernel version: 5.15.0-119-generic
Launching cheese, it says: no device found.
The laptop has a physical switch (shutter) to block off the camera, but the switch is not activated.

Please check if the issue is present in Ubuntu 24.04 (download the ISO and write it to a USB, and test in a live session)

Yes it does work

Recent devices have better support in recent versions of Ubuntu, as it comes with a later version of Linux Kernel and firmware. In this particular laptop, installing Ubuntu 24.04 solves the issue.

After upgrading to Ubuntu 24.04 my camera worked for a while but now stopped working again.

Can you give 24.10 a try?

No, I am on 24.04.1 and plan to stay on it until the next LTS release.

Can you still check if 24.10 has a working camera? If it does, then installing the latest mainline kernel in 24.04 may help. Also, what is the output of lsusb when the camera works and it does not work? Please add the output to your question

The output of lsusb was already added in the question. As you can see the camera is not present. I don't think trying one more kernel will solve the problem, I cannot keep doing that every time a new kernel is released. I also see "usb usb1-port1: unable to enumerate USB device" in my gnome logs, not sure if it helps.

Sorry I don't understand what you mean. The goal is to install the latest kernel, which will hopefully fix the issue, and then be done with it. I don't see what you need to keep doing every time a new kernel is released\

You told me that switching to 24.04 will fix it, and it did not. Now you say I should try 24.10. I can imagine this going on forever. What I am looking for is a method to diagnose and then fix the problem.

@RaduM. I am just a volunteer trying to help. I did not tell you switching to 24.04 will fix it. I had only suggested that new versions have better support, so it may work, and it did work partially. If you don't want to try different things and figure out which one works best, then you are on your own. You can stay with 24.04 until the next LTS which will most likely have the issue fixed.
